# Postgresql - Unable to see exact Query or Transaction that blocked my actual Transaction

Tags: postgresql

Note: I'm using DBeaver 21.1.3 as my PostgreSQL development tool.

For my testing, I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_sk1(n numeric(2));
```

then I have disabled Auto-Commit on my DBEaver to verify whether I can see the blocking query for my other transaction.

[image: Disabled_Auto_Commit.png]

I have then executed an insert on my table:

```
INSERT INTO test_sk1(n) values(10);
```

Now this insert transaction is un-committed, which will block the table.

Then I have taken another new SQL window and tried alter command on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE test_sk1 ADD COLUMN v VARCHAR(2);
```

Now I see the alter transaction got blocked.
But when I verified in the locks, I see that this Alter transaction got blocked by "Show search_path;' transaction, where I'm expecting "INSERT..." transaction as blocking query.

[image: Show_Search_Path_Blocking_Query.png]

I used below query to fetch the lock:

```
SELECT p1.pid,
       p1.query as blocked_query,
       p2.pid as blocked_by_pid,
       p2.query AS blocking_query
  FROM pg_stat_activity p1, pg_stat_activity p2
 WHERE p2.pid IN (SELECT UNNEST(pg_blocking_pids(p1.pid)))
   AND cardinality(pg_blocking_pids(p1.pid)) > 0;
```

Why is this happening on our databases?

Answer (score 1):

Try using psql for such experiments. DBeaver and many other tools will execute many SQL statements that you didn't intend to run.

The query that you see in `pg_stat_activity` is just the latest query done by that process, not necessarily the one locking any resource.

Comment: As suggested, I tried to look for the locks in psql and I still found the same query lock. I still see the blocking query as "SHOW search_path;".

Comment: @SumanKK what does it say under `application_name`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, DBeaver’s SQL editor tries to update the information about the current catalog/schema after executing each query. You can toggle this off by unchecking the
Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Processing -> Refresh active schema after SQL execution and see if it changes what
you see in the session browser.